# SelectToken() with whitespace in path

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I recently upgraded from Json.Net 50r6 to 60r6. Consider the following json:

```
{
    "room list": {
        "regular": [
            {
                "single": {
                    "beds": 1,
                    "bedtype": "double",
                    "balcony": "no"
                }
            }, {
                "double": {
                    "beds": 2,
                    "bedtype": "double",
                    "balcony": "no"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In 50r6, this code snippet works correctly:

```
    Dim j As JObject = JObject.Parse(line)

    Dim jt As JToken = j.SelectToken("room list")
```

In 60r6, I get an error:

> "Unexpected character while parsing path:  "

Is this a bug? The issue resolves in 60r6 if I change the json and `SelectToken()` method to "roomlist".

Edit: I also get the same error with `SelectToken()` if the passed parameter contains a parenthesis.

Comment: Seems to be a bug and it still exists.   I found the solution by accident when watching object in VS debug.  I also found that keys with single quotes don't work either.    Trying to find another parser.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change it to:

```
Dim jt As JToken = j.SelectToken("['room list']")
```

Comment: Thanks James for your prompt and accurate reply. Is this documented, I couldn't find it.